# Let $u_1 = (a,1,-1)$, $u_2 = (-1,a,1)$, $u_3 = (1,-1,a)$. For what values of a are $u_1, u_2, u_3$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u_1 = (a,1,-1)$, $u_2 = (-1,a,1)$, $u_3 = (1,-1,a)$. For what values of a are $u_1, u_2, u_3$ linearly independent?

Can someone show me the way to solve this kind of question? Thank you.

Comment: Since these are three three dimensional vectors, you can set'em up in a matrix and compute the determinant.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

The vectors $u_i$ are said to be linearly indepedent iff $\sum_i \alpha_i u_i = 0$ implies that $\alpha_i = 0$ for all $i$...

... but maybe computing $\det{(u_1,u_2,u_3)}$ is faster.

**SPOILER**:

> $$\det{(u_1,u_2,u_3)} = a ( 3 +a^2) = 0 \implies a = \{0,\mathrm{i} \, \sqrt{3}, -\mathrm{i} \, \sqrt{3} \}. $$